# 2560x1440 resolution on 16.04 and ATI/AMD Radeon HD4670 card

Tags: drivers, 16.04, multiple-monitors, radeon, display-resolution

I'm trying to setup two monitor configuration on my laptop with dual OS setup (ubuntu 16.04 and win7) connecting 27" Dell u2717d monitor via DisplayPort.

I have single video adapter ATI/AMD Radeon HD4670 (RV730)

I'm sure, that my video card supports native 2560x1440 resolution because it works in Win7 without any problems on the same laptop. So it is 100% not a card problem.

But in Ubuntu I can choose only 2048x1080@24Hz.
I tried to add additional modes to xrandr and start new output:

```
$ cvt 2560 1440 60
 2560x1440 59.96 Hz (CVT 3.69M9) hsync: 89.52 kHz; pclk: 312.25 MHz
Modeline "2560x1440_60.00"  312.25  2560 2752 3024 3488  1440 1443 1448 1493 -hsync +vsync
$sudo xrandr --newmode "2560x1440_60.00"  312.25  2560 2752 3024 3488  1440 1443 1448 1493 -hsync +vsync
$sudo xrandr --addmode DisplayPort-0 2560x1440_60.00
```

But after that I just get black screen and monitor-provided message that signal from my laptop not found.

How can I achieve native 2560x1440 resolution on my Ubuntu 16.04?

I'm new to Linux world, so I'm asking for help and will be thankful for a detailed answer or steps to resolve the issue.

Update: 
output of `sudo sh -c "lsb_release -sd; dmidecode -s system-product-name; echo ==; lshw -c display; echo ==; xrandr --verbose; cat /etx/X11/xorg.conf; echo ==; ls /sys/class/drm/*/edid | xargs -i{} sh -c \"echo {}; parse-edid < {}\""`

```
    Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
    Studio XPS 1645
    ==
    *-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: RV730/M96-XT [Mobility Radeon HD 4670]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=radeon latency=0
       resources: irq:30 memory:d0000000-dfffffff ioport:2000(size=256)              memory:cfef0000-cfefffff memory:cfe00000-cfe1ffff
==
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 2048 x 2160, maximum 8192 x 8192
VGA-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
    Identifier: 0x51
    Timestamp:  375584
    Subpixel:   no subpixels
    Clones:    
    CRTCs:      0 1
    Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
               filter: 
    scaling mode: None 
        supported: None, Full, Center, Full aspect
    load detection: 1 
        range: (0, 1)
HDMI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
    Identifier: 0x52
    Timestamp:  375584
    Subpixel:   horizontal rgb
    Clones:    
    CRTCs:      0 1
    Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
               filter: 
    audio: auto 
        supported: off, on, auto
    scaling mode: None 
        supported: None, Full, Center, Full aspect
    dither: off 
        supported: off, on
    underscan vborder: 0 
        range: (0, 128)
    underscan hborder: 0 
        range: (0, 128)
    underscan: off 
        supported: off, on, auto
    coherent: 1 
        range: (0, 1)
LVDS connected primary 1920x1080+128+1080 (0x56) normal (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 193mm
    Identifier: 0x53
    Timestamp:  375584
    Subpixel:   horizontal rgb
    Gamma:      1.0:1.0:1.0
    Brightness: 1.0
    Clones:    
    CRTC:       0
    CRTCs:      0 1
    Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
               filter: 
    EDID: 
        00ffffffffffff0006afed1100000000
        01130103902213780ac8959e57549226
        0f505400000001010101010101010101
        0101010101014c36805e703846401e14
        aa0058c11000001a4c36805e70384640
        1e14aa0058c11000001a000000fe004b
        30323654804231353648573100000000
        00000000000000000002010a202000c9
    scaling mode: Full 
        supported: None, Full, Center, Full aspect
  1920x1080 (0x56) 139.000MHz +HSync -VSync *current +preferred
        h: width  1920 start 1950 end 1970 total 2014 skew    0 clock  69.02KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1090 end 1100 total 1150           clock  60.01Hz
  1680x1050 (0x57) 146.250MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1680 start 1784 end 1960 total 2240 skew    0 clock  65.29KHz
        v: height 1050 start 1053 end 1059 total 1089           clock  59.95Hz
  1400x1050 (0x58) 121.750MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1400 start 1488 end 1632 total 1864 skew    0 clock  65.32KHz
        v: height 1050 start 1053 end 1057 total 1089           clock  59.98Hz
  1280x1024 (0x59) 109.000MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1368 end 1496 total 1712 skew    0 clock  63.67KHz
        v: height 1024 start 1027 end 1034 total 1063           clock  59.89Hz
  1440x900 (0x5a) 106.500MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1440 start 1528 end 1672 total 1904 skew    0 clock  55.93KHz
        v: height  900 start  903 end  909 total  934           clock  59.89Hz
  1280x960 (0x5b) 101.250MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1360 end 1488 total 1696 skew    0 clock  59.70KHz
        v: height  960 start  963 end  967 total  996           clock  59.94Hz
  1280x854 (0x5c) 89.250MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1352 end 1480 total 1680 skew    0 clock  53.12KHz
        v: height  854 start  857 end  867 total  887           clock  59.89Hz
  1280x800 (0x5d) 83.500MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1352 end 1480 total 1680 skew    0 clock  49.70KHz
        v: height  800 start  803 end  809 total  831           clock  59.81Hz
  1280x720 (0x5e) 74.500MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1344 end 1472 total 1664 skew    0 clock  44.77KHz
        v: height  720 start  723 end  728 total  748           clock  59.86Hz
  1152x768 (0x5f) 71.750MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1152 start 1216 end 1328 total 1504 skew    0 clock  47.71KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  781 total  798           clock  59.78Hz
  1024x768 (0x60) 63.500MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1024 start 1072 end 1176 total 1328 skew    0 clock  47.82KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  775 total  798           clock  59.92Hz
  800x600 (0x61) 38.250MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width   800 start  832 end  912 total 1024 skew    0 clock  37.35KHz
        v: height  600 start  603 end  607 total  624           clock  59.86Hz
  848x480 (0x62) 31.500MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width   848 start  872 end  952 total 1056 skew    0 clock  29.83KHz
        v: height  480 start  483 end  493 total  500           clock  59.66Hz
  720x480 (0x63) 26.750MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width   720 start  744 end  808 total  896 skew    0 clock  29.85KHz
        v: height  480 start  483 end  493 total  500           clock  59.71Hz
  640x480 (0x64) 23.750MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width   640 start  664 end  720 total  800 skew    0 clock  29.69KHz
        v: height  480 start  483 end  487 total  500           clock  59.38Hz
DisplayPort-0 connected 2048x1080+0+0 (0x65) normal (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 597mm x 336mm
    Identifier: 0x54
    Timestamp:  375584
    Subpixel:   horizontal rgb
    Gamma:      1.0:1.0:1.0
    Brightness: 1.0
    Clones:    
    CRTC:       1
    CRTCs:      0 1
    Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
               filter: 
    EDID: 
        00ffffffffffff0010acea4053333538
        1b1a0104a53c22783aee95a3544c9926
        0f5054a54b00714fa9408180d1c00101
        010101010101565e00a0a0a029503020
        350055502100001a000000ff004a3058
        594e363739383533530a000000fc0044
        454c4c205532373137440a20000000fd
        00324b1e5819010a20202020202001a0
        02031cf14f9005040302071601061112
        1513141f23091f0783010000023a8018
        71382d40582c450055502100001e7e39
        00a080381f4030203a0055502100001a
        011d007251d01e206e28550055502100
        001ebf1600a08038134030203a005550
        2100001a000000000000000000000000
        00000000000000000000000000000072
    audio: auto 
        supported: off, on, auto
    scaling mode: None 
        supported: None, Full, Center, Full aspect
    dither: off 
        supported: off, on
    underscan vborder: 0 
        range: (0, 128)
    underscan hborder: 0 
        range: (0, 128)
    underscan: off 
        supported: off, on, auto
    coherent: 1 
        range: (0, 1)
  2048x1080 (0x65) 58.230MHz +HSync -VSync *current
        h: width  2048 start 2096 end 2128 total 2208 skew    0 clock  26.37KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1083 end 1093 total 1099           clock  24.00Hz
  1920x1080i (0x66) 74.250MHz +HSync +VSync Interlace
        h: width  1920 start 2008 end 2052 total 2200 skew    0 clock  33.75KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1094 total 1125           clock  60.00Hz
  1920x1080i (0x67) 74.250MHz +HSync +VSync Interlace
        h: width  1920 start 2448 end 2492 total 2640 skew    0 clock  28.12KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1094 total 1125           clock  50.00Hz
  1920x1080i (0x68) 74.176MHz +HSync +VSync Interlace
        h: width  1920 start 2008 end 2052 total 2200 skew    0 clock  33.72KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1094 total 1125           clock  59.94Hz
  1280x720 (0x69) 74.250MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1390 end 1430 total 1650 skew    0 clock  45.00KHz
        v: height  720 start  725 end  730 total  750           clock  60.00Hz
  1280x720 (0x6a) 74.250MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1720 end 1760 total 1980 skew    0 clock  37.50KHz
        v: height  720 start  725 end  730 total  750           clock  50.00Hz
  1280x720 (0x6b) 74.176MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1390 end 1430 total 1650 skew    0 clock  44.96KHz
        v: height  720 start  725 end  730 total  750           clock  59.94Hz
  1024x768 (0x6c) 78.800MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1024 start 1040 end 1136 total 1312 skew    0 clock  60.06KHz
        v: height  768 start  769 end  772 total  800           clock  75.08Hz
  1024x768 (0x6d) 65.000MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width  1024 start 1048 end 1184 total 1344 skew    0 clock  48.36KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  777 total  806           clock  60.00Hz
  800x600 (0x6e) 49.500MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width   800 start  816 end  896 total 1056 skew    0 clock  46.88KHz
        v: height  600 start  601 end  604 total  625           clock  75.00Hz
  800x600 (0x6f) 40.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width   800 start  840 end  968 total 1056 skew    0 clock  37.88KHz
        v: height  600 start  601 end  605 total  628           clock  60.32Hz
  720x576 (0x70) 27.000MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   720 start  732 end  796 total  864 skew    0 clock  31.25KHz
        v: height  576 start  581 end  586 total  625           clock  50.00Hz
  720x576i (0x71) 13.500MHz -HSync -VSync Interlace
        h: width   720 start  732 end  795 total  864 skew    0 clock  15.62KHz
        v: height  576 start  580 end  586 total  625           clock  50.00Hz
  720x480 (0x72) 27.027MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   720 start  736 end  798 total  858 skew    0 clock  31.50KHz
        v: height  480 start  489 end  495 total  525           clock  60.00Hz
  720x480 (0x73) 27.000MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   720 start  736 end  798 total  858 skew    0 clock  31.47KHz
        v: height  480 start  489 end  495 total  525           clock  59.94Hz
  720x480i (0x74) 13.514MHz -HSync -VSync Interlace
        h: width   720 start  739 end  801 total  858 skew    0 clock  15.75KHz
        v: height  480 start  488 end  494 total  525           clock  60.00Hz
  720x480i (0x75) 13.500MHz -HSync -VSync Interlace
        h: width   720 start  739 end  801 total  858 skew    0 clock  15.73KHz
        v: height  480 start  488 end  494 total  525           clock  59.94Hz
  640x480 (0x76) 31.500MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   640 start  656 end  720 total  840 skew    0 clock  37.50KHz
        v: height  480 start  481 end  484 total  500           clock  75.00Hz
  640x480 (0x77) 25.200MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   640 start  656 end  752 total  800 skew    0 clock  31.50KHz
        v: height  480 start  490 end  492 total  525           clock  60.00Hz
  640x480 (0x78) 25.175MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   640 start  656 end  752 total  800 skew    0 clock  31.47KHz
        v: height  480 start  490 end  492 total  525           clock  59.94Hz
  720x400 (0x79) 28.320MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width   720 start  738 end  846 total  900 skew    0 clock  31.47KHz
        v: height  400 start  412 end  414 total  449           clock  70.08Hz
cat: /etx/X11/xorg.conf: No such file or directory
==
/sys/class/drm/card0-DP-1/edid
sh: 1: parse-edid: not found
/sys/class/drm/card0-HDMI-A-1/edid
sh: 1: parse-edid: not found
/sys/class/drm/card0-LVDS-1/edid
sh: 1: parse-edid: not found
/sys/class/drm/card0-VGA-1/edid
sh: 1: parse-edid: not found
```

Comment: Try smaller refresh rate > cvt 2560 1440 40

Comment: Tried 50 and 30, but no success

Comment: it sounds like the windows driver may be using different firmware on the card. which driver are you using

Comment: @TopaZ, Could you [edit] the question and output of `sudo sh -c "lsb_release -sd; dmidecode -s system-product-name; echo ==; lshw -c display; echo ==; xrandr --verbose; cat /etx/X11/xorg.conf; echo ==; ls /sys/class/drm/*/edid | xargs -i{} sh -c \"echo {}; parse-edid < {}\""`

Comment: despite looking scary the above command line from user.dz is just reporting info and not doing evil.

Comment: :) thank you @Amias for the check , `sudo` always brings attention speciallly with such long command . I'm obliged to use root level for `dmidecode` & `lshw`

Comment: @user.dz, added output for your command. Do you see anything suspicious there?

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem with Radeon HD4250. I had no problem getting desired resolution (2560x1080 in my case) on Windows 10 (with reduced refresh rates), but I was stuck with 1920x1080 on Linux.

Then I found [this post](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=228014#p1209813), and tried [umc](https://sourceforge.net/projects/umc/files/umc/umc-0.2/umc-0.2.tar.gz/download). The modeline from umc works perfectly on my desktop(openSUSE). If you are still using Ubuntu, I would recommend giving it a shot. Here's a sample.

```
> umc 2560 1440 60 --rbt

# 2560x1440x59.95 @ 88.787kHz
Modeline "2560x1440x59.95"  241.500000  2560 2608 2640 2720  1440 1443 1447 1481  +HSync -VSync

> umc 2560 1440 50 --rbt

# 2560x1440x49.95 @ 73.621kHz
Modeline "2560x1440x49.95"  200.250000  2560 2608 2640 2720  1440 1443 1447 1474  +HSync -VSync
```